# upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 failed. Please help fix

Tags: upgrade, 14.10

So I figured since the final was 2 days away I would do the upgrade now. Did the same thing from 13.10 to 14.04 and no major issues other than to reinstall Nvidia driver. This time a bunch of things are not configuring and when I exit and try things manually I get all these dependency issues:

```
dpkg: error processing package libmrm4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initscripts
 util-linux
 e2fsprogs
 x11-common
 procps
 dbus
 kmod
 module-init-tools
 udev
 initramfs-tools
 brltty
 bluez
 consolekit
 upstart-bin
 grub-common
 mountall
 plymouth
 ifupdown
 upstart
 friendly-recovery
 resolvconf
 accountsservice
 language-selector-common
 systemd
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 cups-daemon
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
 printer-driver-hpcups
 hplip
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 printer-driver-gutenprint
 cups-driver-gutenprint
 dbus-x11
 gcr
 gnome-keyring
 libice6:amd64
 libice6:i386
 libsm6:amd64
 libqtgui4:amd64
 libsm6:i386
 libqtgui4:i386
 libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64
 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386
 gconf2
 libgnomevfs2-common
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64
 libkgapi2-2:amd64
 libmotif-common
 libxm4:amd64
 libmrm4:amd64
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the example.

This from a `sudo apt-get -f install`.

I tried clean I tried -upgrade I tried `-f` with the upgrade, I tried `dpkg -a`.

What am I doing wrong? If need be I can back up my `/home` reboot to my 14.04.1 live DVD and reinstall but I am trying not to do that if I can get past this. Any help would be appreciated.

Fairly current desktop with a AMD quad core 64bit chip using 64 bit Ubuntu on a Asus motherboard with a Nvidia 550ti video card  and 8GB of DDR3 ram. No other issues with my HW. Plenty of HDD space as well.

Again any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `abort-after` option ? Or `force-bad-version` ? Or `configure-any` ? Set those in the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg`. See `info dpkg` for details.

Comment: or trie to install only a few programs (eg. `sudo apt-get install procps`)